# ITMS-90034 Apple App Store Submission Error

Tags: ios, xcode5.1.1

I am a PC person, and not much of a coder, so I have a developer building an app for distribution to the Apple App Store.

It's done, working great, but he tells me there is problems during the submission.  He got an error ITMS-90034

Not having a Mac or the ability to run Xcode or the Application Loader, I'm in the dark here.

What does that error indicate, and why would it take multiple days to solve this problem?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

**ITMS 90034** means there is problem while getting the certificate(.p12) which you can see in Keychain Access, please check the certificate with valid provisioning profile.

I have faced this Issue after cleaning my Keychain Access where I installed certificate multiple times then it's linked with xcode6.0 where I am able to upload the build using Apploader.

you can prefer below link for more details.

[ITMS 90034 Resolution](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/53903-missing-or-invalid-signature-not-signed-using-an-apple-submission-ticket/)

Thanks !!!